# Why mysql query takes long before received results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 2 tables with thousands of data and i will look for matches 1:1 on both tables. I have the query below, but when the limit is already beyond 1000 the return starts to slow down, it took almost an hour before I receive a result, I am using my local xampp as database for this and have a 4G(3.4G usable) RAM PC.

Is there any other way to enhance and make the query faster?

Thank you in advance for those who will help.

```
SELECT a.rNum,
        a.cDate,
        a.cTime,
        a.aNumber,
        a.bNumber,
        a.duration,
        a.tag,
        a.aNumber2,
        a.bNumber2,
        'hasMatch',
        a.concatDate,
        a.timeMinutes
FROM tableOne a
INNER JOIN
tableTwo b ON a.aNumber2 = b.aNumber2 
AND a.bNumber2 = b.bNumber2
WHERE a.hasMatch = 'valid'
AND (a.duration - b.duration) <= 3  
AND (a.duration - b.duration) >= -3 
AND TIMEDIFF(a.concatDate,b.concatDate) <= 3
AND TIMEDIFF(a.concatDate,b.concatDate) >= -3
LIMIT 0,100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious question is:  do you have indexes?

As written, the best indexes to try on on `tableOne(aNumber1, aNumber2)` and `tableTwo(bNumber1, bNumber2)`.

If you provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do, there might be further suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. 

The two tables came from two different users. Based on the conditions that they both have the same aNumber2 and bNumber2 and the time difference is less than 3seconds either negative or positive only then with both entry on both tables will be tagged as match, however if a single entry has multiple match on other table, only 1 entry will tagged on the other table the rest will stay as is. But aNumber and bNumber on both tables can be different either the other one has a prefix and the other has no prefix or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can try many steps in a nutshell

- First perform an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) statement and act accordingly
- Make sure the compared attributes are of equal length
- Make your keys as short as possible
- Consider adding indexes where you need too, (in the WHERE clause if the values are suitable for indexing, and you perform this query very often)
- Make an ANALYZE TABLE
- Avoid any redundant data or with NULL values as much as possible